# ActiveStorage Blobs table, possible to ignore column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm doing a Rails 6.1 upgrade at the moment and wondering if there's a way to set the new `service_name` column to be [ignored](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-ignored_columns). I know how to do this with an ActiveRecord table, but not a Rails' internal table (not sure what to call it).

So above details aside, how does one set a column in the `active_storage_blobs` table to be ignored?

Comment: You would do it by monkeypatching the ActiveStorage::Blob class, but why do you think its necissary in the first place?

Comment: yeah, I'd rather not for sure, but, I operate in a busy application that doesn't want to experience down time to do this upgrade. The changes required for ActiveStorage Blobs in 6.1 are a bit of lock step issue. In 6.1 ActiveStorage Blob requires service_name. Ideally I'd be able to backport the change (i.e., run the migration in 6.0), and then I don't have to lock the database/have downtime for the period of the upgrade and migration. However in 6.0 doing this migration doesn't work _unless I can ignore the column_. Could monkeypatch, I'll look into it. Was hoping for an easy "Rails way"

Answer (score 1):

```rb
# app/initializers/active_storage_ignore_service_name_backport.rb

module ActiveStorageIgnoreServiceNameBackport
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    ignored_columns = [:service_name]
  end
end

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.include(ActiveStorageIgnoreServiceNameBackport)
end
```